# Identify anime with island floating in the sky

Tags: story-identification, anime

Very sketchy as I was about 8 the last time I watched it 24 years ago! A boy finds a way to get on a giant floating city which is nearly deserted and at the end I think it gets destroyed by a fleet of ships. That ends my brilliant clues.

I believe it is from the 80s, and was shown on the British TV channel ITV.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds as though it might be [Laputa: Castle in the Sky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky).

It was released in 1986, the city could only be reached by airship, and it was destroyed at the end, but not by the airships - it was destroyed so that its secrets could not fall into the wrong hands.

[image: Laputa]

These are the two main characters, befriending the last of the city's guardian robots:

[image: Pazu and Sheeta]